# Like to see git branch at a glance in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I see the current git branch at a glance in my intellij? In eclipse I can see it at project root folder. Is there any configuration that I missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the current git branch in the lower right corner:

[image]